# Stuck with "Launching new emulator"

Tags: application-development, android, emulation

I'm a windows user and I decided to use ubuntu 12.04 for developing android apps

I googled instruction for installing sdk and jdk.. i follow every steps.. and i've create a test application "Hello World" using android 2.1 and here is the problem..

```
[2012-08-05 23:20:46 - TestApp1] Android Launch!<br>
[2012-08-05 23:20:46 - TestApp1] adb is running normally.<br>
[2012-08-05 23:20:46 - TestApp1] Performing joshua.testapp1.MainActivity activity launch<br>
[2012-08-05 23:20:46 - TestApp1] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Dev2.1' is not available. Launching new emulator.<br>
[2012-08-05 23:20:46 - TestApp1] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Dev2.1'
```

yep.. thats all in the console.. and no emulator showing up....

Comment: Do you have an emulator created. To test this goto SDK directory/tools and run android avd in terminal. If you get an empty list view, you need to create an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. The solution was quite simple. Install the driver for my video card Gforce 9600GT.